# drop down multiple select checkbox save other table code first mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

value comes from database display on the drop-down when chek did not get value and sav the value in other tables.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var expanded = false;

    function showCheckboxes() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        if (!expanded) {
            checkboxes.style.display = "block";
            expanded = true;
        } else {
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
            expanded = false;
        }

            }
</script>
```

```css
<style>

    .multiselect {
        width: 200px;
    }

    .selectBox {
        position: relative;
    }

        .selectBox select {
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    .overSelect {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    #checkboxes {
        display: none;
        border: 1px #dadada solid;
    }

        #checkboxes label {
            display: block;
        }

            #checkboxes label:hover {
                background-color: #1e90ff;
            }
</style>
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
            <select>
                <option>Select an option</option>
            </select>
            <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="checkboxes">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <label for="@item.Id">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Id" />@item.FName
                </label>

            }



        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: List<ProfileDemo> ProfileDemoobj = new List<ProfileDemo>();

Comment: var abc = dbContext.profileDemos.ToList();

Comment: return View(abc);

Comment: Data come from database in the dropdown  checkbox then check value save in other table

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more?@ugrshen sharma